# How to construct an ASP.NET Core MVC route with prefix that might contain the same character as the rest of the url?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to construct a route that matches the following urls:

- /r-cars
- /r-old-cars
- /r-very-old-cars

Everything behind the prefix 'r-' should be passed to an Action as a parameter. I constructed the following route template:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    ... 
    template: "r-{urlPart}" 
    ... 
)
```

This route does exactly what is intended and 'cars', 'old-cars' and 'very-old-cars' are extracted and passed as an argument to my Action method.

However, if I have the following url:

- /r-older-cars

This route does not match and the Action is not triggered. I guess this is because the 'r-' is occuring twice in the url - but I don't really understand why this is a problem and how I could write a route that
just defines the 'r-' as a prefix that should occur at the very beginning of the url and simply pass everything behind that as one string to my Action.

(I'm using AspNetCore.App 2.2.0)

Can anybody give advice on that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what happens if you start your template with a slash `template: "/r-{urlPart}"`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make a difference: '/r-older-cars' doesn't match, the others do.

Comment: an easy way, when not really clean, imho would be to validate the parameter inside your action. like `Request.Path.StartsWithSegments($"/r-{urlPart}")`, if it matches all it is good if not, extract it manually

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is that I would need a catch all route for this Action then (the Action is not triggered at the moment for '/r-older-cars'). Unfortunately I already have another catch-all route for another purpose.

Comment: I guess I found a solution (see my answer). Anyways thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a solution:

In startup.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    ... 
    "{urlPart:regex(^r-.+$)}"
    ... 
)
```

By this way the Action gets triggered for all urls starting with '/r-' (also the url '/r-older-cars' gets matched).

Since the 'r-' is now part of the Action parameter I put the following code at the beginning of my Action method:

```
urlPart = urlPart.Substring(2);
```

Now urlPart contains 'cars', 'old-cars', etc. and everything else works fine.

Comment: yeah looks good, let's hope you don't need /r- anywhere else ;)